# Ubuntu20 Bluetooth service unavailable after booting in W10

Tags: dual-boot, unity, bluetooth

Since my last windows update, when I reboot in Ubuntu I can't activate bluetooth.
I'm with ubuntu20.4 and Unity.
The bluetooth icon is not present in the upper-right corner and in the setting's bluetooth page it's disabled. When I enable it, close the window and re-open it's still disabled.

It's like Windows has locked the bluetooth.

Is there a way to unlock it from ubuntu ?

My configuration : Dell XPS15 2020

Comment: I have similar issues